# Finding the number of perfect squares that divides $6!7!8!$

Tags: combinatorics

How many perfect squares divides the product $6!7!8!$ I started by first factoring out and I got the prime factors to be
$//(3^6)(2^{15})(5^3)(7^2)//$ but I do not know how to go on from here please I need help.

Answer (score 6):

As you point out the prime factorization is $2^{15} 3^6 5^3 7^2$. Any square divisor must  have the form $2^{2a} 3^{2b} 5^{2c} 7^{2d}$. Thus $a \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$, $b \in \{0,1,2,3\}$, $c \in \{0,1\}$, and $d \in \{0,1\}$. There are a total of $8 \cdot 4 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 = 128$ ways to select the exponents, so there are 128 square divisors.